# Simple PHP OOP Query null

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to write a simple program that queries sql to the database using object orientated programing. I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\core\classes\core.php:11 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\core\classes\core.php(23):
>   core->query('SELECT * FROM c...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\core\classes\core.php(27): test->test() #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\core\init.php(6):
>   require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #3 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\learning\core\classes\core.php on line 11

```
<?php
class core{
    protected $db, $results;
    private $rows;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','test');
    }

    public function query($sql){
        $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }

    public function rows(){
        for($x = 1; $x <= $this->db->affected_rows; $x++){
            $this->rows[] = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        return $this->rows;
    }
}
class test extends core{
    public function test(){
        $this->query("SELECT * FROM currentseason");

    }
}


  $test = new test();
    $test->test();
    ?>
```

Comment: It would seem that `$this->db` is `NULL`, you should be checking the result of `$this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','test')` to make sure it succeeded.

Comment: The real issue here is that without a `__construct()` method, PHP will also use a method named the same as the class as the constructor so unfortunately OP, `test#test()` is your constructor. I'd say this little fact is not widely known (these days) so downvotes are a little harsh.

Comment: @Nick that's not necessary if OP has [set MySQLi to throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/283366) (which is always a good idea IMO)

Comment: @Phil definitely a good idea but seemingly one that has been adopted more by the PDO crowd...

Comment: The problem was that the method name "test" was the same name as the class. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not called the parent constructor from the test class.

The PHP docs says:

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a
>   constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct()
>   within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor > then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if
>   it was not declared as private).

I modified your test class as follows:
(with a modified query to a table in my test DB)

```
class test extends core {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function test() {
        $this->query("SELECT * FROM bug_table");
        foreach ($this->rows() as $row) {
            echo $row['category_id'], '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Server
Database
Server
Server
Server
```

...at the same PHP information found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), I changed the `test()` class constructor to `__construct` as you have in the `core` class, but kept the function named `test()` that runs the query. Having a constructor the same name as the class is quickly being deprecated. Depending on your PHP version, run `php -l file.php` at the command line on your file to check any potential issues.

Comment: The problem was the method name "test" was the same name as the class. Thank you for your help!